# ULS Event: "Could not parse content for cells. SuperUserCell = 1, SuperReaderCell = 0, contenttype = Boolean."

Tags: 2010, publishing, uls, cache

In the ULS Logs from the SharePoint 2010 farm, i notice the following Unexpected events occuring when visiting a certain page in the site collection:

ULS Event Message:
Could not parse content for cells.  SuperUserCell = 1, SuperReaderCell = 0, contenttype = Boolean.

> 09-11-2017 11:19:37.28    w3wp.exe (0x1480)   0x89A8  Web Content Management  Publishing Cache    87d7    Unexpected  Could not parse content for cells.  SuperUserCell = 1, SuperReaderCell = 0, contenttype = Boolean.  71f76120-22a2-4973-ab4b-989d2ddf0a73

and

> 09-11-2017 11:21:45.17    w3wp.exe (0x1480)   0x8C0C  Web Content Management  Publishing Cache    87d7    Unexpected  Could not parse content for cells.  SuperUserCell = 1, SuperReaderCell = 1, contenttype = Boolean.  09f2ddc0-8cee-4d0c-8c1f-e8e796e9faf0

Currently, I did not find a solution on the internet.

I've tried:

- IISReset
- Refresh Site Collection Object Cache
- Refresh SharePoint Config Cache

Does anyone recognize this error and have a possible solution?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Does this issue occur on other pages?
Did you have any code on the page?
You can create a new page, then just add some text into it to check if this issue occurs on the new page.